# 'Sorry' as a replacement for 'Excuse me'?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it ok to say 'sorry' where you otherwise would use 'excuse me'?

Example: "Sorry, but could you show me the way to the next train station?"

Comment: I think, based on your example sentence, it is "Sorry (**to disturb you**), but could you show me the way to the next train station?" In this case ('disturbing' the person), using 'sorry' is okay.

Comment: This is probably opinion based, but in a literal sense I would stick to "excuse me" with strangers. You didn't do anything to be sorry for, you are just interrupting someone. (AmE, this might vary based on locale.)

Comment: So 'sorry' is more apologetic than 'excuse me'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Excuse me' or 'pardon me' would be common. One would normally say 'sorry' only after the fact, if one could tell they were interrupting or inconveniencing the person in question. If you use the entire phrase -- "sorry to bother you" -- then yes, but that would still be less common than the simpler "excuse me." Also, see ['the difference between excuse me and sorry'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48083/difference-between-excuse-me-and-sorry)…

Comment: Sorry is understandable as a replacement in my dialect of AmE.  As mentioned by @shin, I would understand it as "sorry to disturb you". Maybe you mean to say it's uncommon in your dialect? Or there's some other reason to prefer "excuse me"?

Comment: US English - one would only say 'sorry' after the fact, if one could tell they were interrupting or inconveniencing the person in question. If you use the entire phrase -- "sorry to bother you" -- then yes, but that would still be less common than the simpler "excuse me." Also, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48083/difference-between-excuse-me-and-sorry

Comment: I  think the elaboration from your comment would make your answer more helpful. "It doesn't work" might lead learners to think it's completely wrong, which it's not. Comments on SE sites are temporary, so it's a good idea to get them into an answer or question if the discussion is helpful.  Editing will also allow me to retract my down vote.

Comment: Colleen - edited per your suggestion.

Comment: +1 for finding a relevant discussion on EL&U by the way. I think it's helpful  to see  something explained in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's fine to say sorry instead of excuse me, it's not as common.

Comment: I hope you elaborate more - "it's not as common" (How? Why? What are the instances?) Just a tip. :)

Comment: Oops. Forgot this line - WELCOME to ELL!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use the complete phrase "Sorry to disturb you, but..." or "Excuse me, but ..."