# Excuse me and I'm sorry

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

can you guys show me the most considerable differences between the meaning/usage of excuse me and I'm sorry?

Comment: The question has been answered in the English Language and usage forum. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48083/difference-between-excuse-me-and-sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always seen the difference as a perception or colloquial difference.

- "I'm sorry" is used specifically when the speaker regrets an action or situation.
- "Excuse me" is used in a number of non-apologetic scenarios. For example, when trying to get someone's attention.

This may be an oversimplification of the differences, but I hope it helps.

There's also a similar question here:
 ['Sorry' as a replacement for 'Excuse me'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/sorry-as-a-replacement-for-excuse-me?noredirect=1&lq=1)